# Insert API Call in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem to insert a API call with request in mongodb with mongoose. I am very new in this topic. Need your help!!! Here ist my test.js, how can i solve this problem any ideas. My target is to save the Api call from the url and then update it all 30 min but at the moment i was very happy when i could save the call. For all help i am very grateful.

When i start with node test.js then i get only the ids in mongodb not more.

````
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const port = 3000;

const dbUrl = process.env.xxx || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testingDB';

mongoose
  .connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection ready');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Create a Schema
const coinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  coin_id: Number,
  name: String,
  symbol: String,
  market_cap_rank: String,
  thumb: String,
  small: String,
  large: String,
  slug: String,
  price_btc: Number,
  score: Number,
});
//Create a Model with collection coins
const Coin = mongoose.model('Coin', coinSchema);

app.get('/testing', async (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending';

  request({ url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      Coin.insertMany(response.body.coins);
      console.log(response.body.coins);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server ready on port ${port}`);
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
request({ url: 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending', json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
  // ...
  Coin.insertMany(body.coins.map(({ item }) => item));
});
```